# mongodb in production

Tags: deployment, mongodb, production

We are planning to use mongodb in production for a subset of data. In past, I have read that mongodb has issues with blocking writes and write durability. Are they resolved with 2.0 release? Are there anything else which one should be careful of, before deploying mongodb in production?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your concerns, or what you've read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with blocking writes. Atomic write operations is MongoDB's strategy to deal with concurrency and consistency. This does mean that if your write load is high (monitor using mongostat tool and keep an eye on "locked %", this should typically stay very low) you will have to start using sharding to minimize per-instance write lock contention

Durability actually has been improved in 2.0 with the journaling feature but was already pretty solid with replica sets. Basically, if you invest the resources (instances) then durability and fail-over is pretty solid in MongoDB. Journaling improves (crash) recovery more than anything.

TL;DR with the appropriate measures MongoDB is a production ready storage solution.